# convert a html book to a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, html

How can I convert a html book (consisting of a number of html files linked to each other) to a pdf file on Ubuntu?

Hope the resulting pdf file can have bookmarks according to the structures of the html book.

The html book can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/files/audacity/2.1.0/audacity-manual-2.1.0.zip/download). Extract it, and go to `help`, and the directory `manual` is the html book.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/)? It manages to convert between tons and tons of things (including PDF and HTML).

Comment: thanks. how shall I use pandoc to convert?

Comment: Their [documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html) should take care of that :)

Comment: thanks. in the extracted directory from the zip file, the html book is in the directory `help/manual`. Its first page is `index.html`, which contains links to a lot of other htmls in directory `help/manual/man`. Do I have to specify all the html files as inputs to `pandoc`, or just `index.html` and no other html files as input to `pandoc`? If the former, how do you specify the many html files in the correct order?

Comment: That is a good question of which I know not the answer. Though I know of pandoc, I have never personally had a need to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602393/how-to-convert-modern-html-to-pdf

Answer (score 6):

Just use `wkhtmltopdf`

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf

On my Fedora:

- install via

  ```
  dnf install wkhtmltopdf
  ```
- use as

  ```
  wkhtmltopdf in.html out.pdf
  ```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that using `wkhtmltopdf` was already suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211740/377345) by @Wyatt8740; you may want to edit yours to make the difference clearer.

Comment: pdf output looks ¦ ̧à§​à¦Ÿà§​à¦°à¦3⁄4à¦Ÿà§‹à¦ ̧à§​à¦«à¦¿à§Ÿà¦3⁄4à¦°à§‡à¦°

Answer (score 4):

First off, not sure I can get the bookmarks and such made automatically, as nice as that would be.

You can manually add them, though, afterwards.

Try opening the HTML file in firefox, and going to `file -> print` `(ctrl+p)`.
Then, click "Print to File" and click 'PDF'. Then type your file name and select the folder to save it in.

[image]

If you want to automate it, maybe you want [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)?
To install it (in ubuntu or debian or linuxmint or similar), type:
`sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf` was perfect!

Comment: Great! Glad my answer helped someone, all these years later. I'd totally forgotten writing this answer…

Answer (score 4):

You can use package **htmldoc**, which is much easier to get working than pandoc.
It takes a list of html files and resolves the hyperlinks between them to
produce a single pdf with working links, and includes the images.

```
htmldoc $(find help/manual -name '*html' | sort) --outfile  /tmp/out.pdf
```

Of course, it would help to know in what order to collate the html files. I
just sorted them on name.

Unfortunately, on my fedora 20 I got core dumps when I tried to put more
than half the audacity files through at the same time. I got to 440 pages of output though.
Perhaps just not enough memory. YMMV.

Remember for safety to prefer [the real
audacity](http://web.audacityteam.org/) web site or your OS package manager
rather than sourceforge.

Answer (score 4):

You can use chrome headless

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
./chrome --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf index.html
```

Comment: There are multiple html files, and index.html might just be the one with links to the others. Will your chrome command only print the index.html or also the html files linked from it?

Comment: I've actually only tried it with 1 html file

Comment: Renders better than wkhtmltopdf. Lots of errors in the terminal though, and it can't do fonts with gradients. Extra features here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077392/additional-options-in-chrome-headless-print-to-pdf

Answer (score 3):

Some other alternatives:

[weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/) - more up to date and better support for print css commands than something like wkhtmltopdf

[pagedjs](https://pagedjs.org/) / [pagedjs-cli](https://github.com/pubpub/pagedjs-cli) - similar; uses headless chromium in the backend, but abstracts away some of the difficulties

I recommend reading [this tutorial](https://print-css.rocks/) at print-css.rocks, which summarizes a bunch of methods.

Answer (score 1):

You probably alredy have Libreoffice installed so you already have the tool at hand. Here is how:

```
$ libreoffice --headless --norestore --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export MY_HTML_FILE.html
```

If you use windows just replace libreoffice for the equivalent .exe file ( probably libreoffice.exe ).

If you dont have libreoffice installed just go to libreoffice.org for instructions on how to install it.

On unbutu `$ sudo apt install libreoffice`

Answer (score 0):

I have print to pdf a bunch of html files using "chromium headless" (the chrome base browser).

```
chromium --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=./${filename}.pdf --no-margins ./${filename}.html
```

A bash script to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for files in $(ls . )
do
    filename=`echo $files | cut -d. -f1`
    chromium --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=./${filename}.pdf --no-margins ./${filename}.html
done
```